# In a town of a population of 1825, what is the probability that each day at least one has birthday?

Tags: probability-distributions, balls-in-bins

**Attempt**

Since this is a success/failure sample, I figured the event X : number of people who have birthday the chosen day follows a binomial distribution, with $ n = 1825$ and $p = 1/365$. Since $n \gg 1$ and $p \ll 1$, I can use an approach for the experiment via Poisson distribution with $λ=n \cdot p = 1825 \cdot (1/365) = 5$

$\Rightarrow X$~$P(5)$

$P[X>=1] = 1 - P[X < 1] = 1- P[X=0] = 1- e^{-5}$

Is this correct? I was told the answer should be 8.5%

Comment: $1 - e^{-5}$ corresponds to a probability of about $99.32$ % hence it's not correct.

Comment: @VonNeumann Yes I know that. I am asking if my solution is correct. Maybe the result I was told was incorrect.

Comment: You calculated the odds of one or more person having their birthday one a specific day, but you want to calculate the odds of every day having at least one birthday, so that is why it is not correct.

Comment: @PeldePinda Would you mind telling me how the solution is derived? I have been trying to solve this problem for quite a while without any better result..

Comment: I don't know either. Here's my try, maybe it helps you: If we define $X_i := $the number of people having their birthday one the $i$'th day of the year, you want to calculate $p = P(X_1 > 0, X_2 > 0, ..., X_{365} > 0)$, but since the events are not independent (if a lot of people have their birthdays on 1st of januari, the odds of someone having their birthday on 2nd of august will be lower, I don't know how to evaluate that.

Comment: @PeldePinda It's okay, thank you anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculation of $1-e^{-5}$ is the probability that a specific day has at least one person with that birthday.  The question asks for the chance that every day has at least one person with that birthday.  If we assume the days are independent the chance that every day has somebody with that birthday is $(1-e^{-5})^{365} \approx 8.478\%$.  The assumption of independence is not correct because the fact that you know somebody has a birthday Jan 1 reduces slightly the chance that somebody has a birthday Jan 2, but it will be close.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Since the days are not independent how would one approach the solution?

Comment: In fact, simulation puts that probability at roughly $0.0822$, while it confirms the $1- e^{-5}$ probability for a specific day.

Comment: @Fib:  If I tell you that nobody has a birthday on Jan 1, the probability that someone has one on Jan 2 increases to $1-e^{-1825/364}\approx 99.3354\%$ compared to $1-e^{-5} \approx 99.3262\%$.  It is not much of a change.  I don't know an easy way to incorporate that, which is why I didn't.

Comment: @RossMillikan Understood, thank you very much.